# Probability of at least one player winning.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Player 1 and Player 2 are playing in a quiz show where there are 8 True or False Questions, and anyone who scores above 5 correct answers wins a small price (All answers must be given and locked in before results). What is the probability of at least one of the 2 players wins?

(I thought about this question when me and friend took part in such a quiz, but couldn't really find an answer.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to answer a 1st question : what is the probability that player 1 wins. (binomial formula, as explained in answers). Then, you can easily count those 3 results : probability both player loose, probability only one player wins, probability both players win. By counting all 3 results, it gives you a way to check if the sum is 1 or not. If the sum is not 1, there was an error somewhere.  An other rule that can help : when there is 'at least' in a question, it is often easier to search the opposite : what is the probability that both players loose ?

Answer (score 1):

Let denote as $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ the number of correct answers achieved by each player. Then each $X_{i}$ will follow a binomial distribution with $8$ trials and success probability $p_{i}$ since I guess each player has a different kind of knowledge. Then you want to calculate the probability that $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>5,X_{2}>5)$. Now I assume that the players are independent and how one answers doesn't affect the other players answers. Then we can rewrite it as $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>5)\mathbb{P}(X_{2}>5)$. And calculate those probabilities with the Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take on account that the asked probability is given by:
$$P(at \ least \ one \ wins) = P(one \ winning ) + P(both \ winning)$$
Supposing every question is answered randomly, each correct answer has $\frac 1 2$ to be chosen. Therefore,
$$P(one \ winning ) = 2 \cdot \sum_{i = 5}^8 {8 \choose i} \cdot (\frac 1 2)^i $$
The 2 is because there are two players, choose enough questions to win and multiply by the probability to be correct.
$$P(both\ winning ) = \sum_{i = 5}^8 {8 \choose i}^2 \cdot (\frac 1 4)^{2i} $$

Comment: With your naming (not really intuitive), the first formula should be : $P(at \ least \ one \ wins) = P(one \ winning ) - P(both \ winning)$